# Oracle - In CLAUSE question when using with multiple values, making it dynamic

Tags: oracle, in-clause

I just spent an hour on google and here trying to get a straight answer for how to do this in Oracle. What I need is the ability to use select in clause that constructed automatically such as

```
select col1 from table1 where id.table IN ('1','2','3');
```

where the id values are passed to the stored procedure inside the array. The associative array has been defined as such:

```
 TYPE varchar_array_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (40)      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

Is there a simple, concrete way to do that? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, if your collection type is defined in PL/SQL (rather than SQL), you cannot use it in SQL because the SQL engine doesn't know how to handle it.

If instead you defined the collection type in SQL, i.e.

```
CREATE TYPE varchar_tbl
    IS TABLE OF varchar2(40);
```

Then you can do something like

```
SELECT col1
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE t1.id IN (SELECT column_value
                   FROM TABLE( <<variable of type varchar2_tbl>> ) )
```

depending on the Oracle version-- the syntax for using collections in SQL has evolved over time-- older versions of Oracle had more complex syntax.

You can convert a PL/SQL associative array (your VARCHAR_ARRAY_TYPE) to a SQL nested table collection in PL/SQL, but that requires iterating through the associative array and filling the nested table, which is a bit of a pain.  Assuming that the `VARCHAR_TBL` nested table collection has been created already

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE varchar_tbl
         IS TABLE OF varchar2(40);
```

you can convert from the associative array to the nested table and use the nested table in a SQL statement like this (using the SCOTT.EMP table)

```
declare
  type varchar_array_type
    is table of varchar2(40)
       index by binary_integer;
  l_associative_array varchar_array_type;
  l_index             binary_integer;
  l_nested_table      varchar_tbl := new varchar_tbl();
  l_cnt               pls_integer;
begin
  l_associative_array( 1 ) := 'FORD';
  l_associative_array( 10 ) := 'JONES';
  l_associative_array( 100 ) := 'NOT A NAME';
  l_associative_array( 75 ) := 'SCOTT';
  l_index := l_associative_array.FIRST;
  while( l_index IS NOT NULL )
  loop
    l_nested_table.EXTEND;
    l_nested_table( l_nested_table.LAST ) :=
             l_associative_array( l_index );
    l_index := l_associative_array.NEXT( l_index );
  end loop;
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO l_cnt
    FROM emp
   WHERE ename IN (SELECT column_value
                     FROM TABLE( l_nested_table ) );
  dbms_output.put_line( 'There are ' || l_cnt || ' employees with a matching name' );
end;
```

Because converting between collection types is a bit of a pain, however, you would generally be better off just using the nested table collection (and passing that to the stored procedure) unless there is a particular reason that the associative array is needed.

Comment: thanks, that's the easy part. how do I dump my array values into that varchar_tbl? I tried few things, all giving me errors. This should be easy but for some reason is horrifically awkward. Ugh.

Comment: also, please explain what you mean by "if your collection type is defined in PL/SQL (rather than SQL), you cannot use it in SQL". Everything we do is inside stored procedures. Please keep that in mind, thanks.

Comment: @gnomixa - Posted an example of converting between collection types.  You can use collection types defined in SQL (i.e. CREATE TYPE) in both SQL and PL/SQL since PL/SQL is built on top of SQL.  You can only use collection types defined in PL/SQL in PL/SQL-- you cannot use those types in SQL.

Comment: thanks for your code. But still not helping. How do I create a temporary table INSIDE my stored procedure(or rather DEFINE the temporary table type)? Is that possible? Or do I have to do through the SQL prompt. thanks again. Can't I just easily create the temporary table in my stored proc???

Comment: You cannot create the SQL collection type in PL/SQL (barring heroic effort and a ton of dynamic SQL & PL/SQL).  You need to create the SQL collection type once as a first-order object and then you can reference it in whatever stored procedures you'd like.  You can declare an instance of the SQL collection type in your stored procedure just as I did here in my anonymous PL/SQL block (l_nested_table is an instance of the varchar_tbl collection type).